# Trying to understand product sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis

Given an arbitrary collection of nonempty sets $(X_\alpha)_{\alpha \in \Omega} $ where $\Omega $ is some index set. Set $X=\prod_{\alpha\in \Omega}X_\alpha $

If $\scr{M}_\alpha $ is an sigma algebra on $X_\alpha $ for all $\alpha $. Then the product sigma algebra on $X$ is generated by $\{\pi^{-1}_\alpha(E_\alpha): E_\alpha \in \scr{M}_\alpha, \alpha \in \Omega\} $

Assume that $\Omega$ is countable and $E_\alpha \in \scr{M}_\alpha$ then the product sigma algebra is generated by $\{\prod E_\alpha : E_\alpha \in \scr{M}_\alpha\}$.

Now the following equality I am not able to see, If $E_\alpha \in \scr{M}_\alpha$ then $\pi^{-1}_\alpha (E_\alpha)=\prod_{\beta\in\Omega}E_\beta$ where $E_\beta=X_\beta$ for $\beta \neq \alpha$.

To my understanding $\pi^{-1}_\alpha (E_\alpha)=\{f:\Omega \to X_\alpha: \pi_\alpha (f)=f(\alpha)\in E_\alpha\}=\prod_{\alpha \in \Omega} E_\alpha$ , why do we need $E_\beta =X_\beta$ for all $\beta \neq \alpha$ and I dont see how the $\Omega$ being countable comes to play.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You technically never defined $\pi_\alpha$ in your post, but I assume it is the projection $\pi_\alpha: X \to X_\alpha$ which sends an element $x=(x_\beta)_{\beta \in \Omega}$ to the component $x_\alpha$.

With that definition of $\pi_\alpha$, the preimage $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E_\alpha)$ is some subset of $X$ and there are no functions $f: \Omega \to X_\alpha$ involved. Instead, by definition
$$\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E_\alpha):= \{(x_\beta)_{\beta \in \Omega} \in X: \pi_\alpha((x_\beta)_{\beta \in \Omega}) \in E_\alpha\} = \{(x_\beta)_{\beta \in \Omega} \in X: x_\alpha \in E_\alpha\}$$
which means there are no conditions on the components $x_\beta$ for $\beta \ne \alpha$. This means they can be chosen freely and by definition of $X= \prod_{\beta \in \Omega} X_\beta$ that means that we can take any $x_\beta \in X_\beta$ (the projection to component $\alpha$ doesn't care about the inputs in the components $\beta \ne \alpha$). So in conclusion
$$\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E_\alpha) = \prod_{\beta \in \Omega} F_\beta$$
where $F_\alpha = E_\alpha$ and $F_\beta = X_\beta$ for all $\beta \ne \alpha$.